# Communication questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Just came across [Does mobile phones use TCP/IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/380698/does-mobile-phones-use-tcp-ip?rq=1).  It was closed for being "off-topic", but I don't get it.

Any idea, why this would qualify as off-topic?

Comment: Good ask though

Answer (score 4):

From the FAQ: https://superuser.com/faq

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware computer
> - software personal and home
> - computer networking
>
> and it is **not** about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, **cell phones or smart phones**, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

The exception for cell phones and smart phones, "*except insofar as they interface with your computer*", does not apply here, as TCP/IP communication (and VoIP) on these phones happen without the interaction of a computer.

Comment: I would say a _smart phone_ **is a computer**. The FAQ does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

This could have been either off topic or not a real question. It's as much about the question and the topic, but also that mobiles on their own are [off topic unless they're connected to the computer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6187/communication-questions-off-topic/6188#6188).

The meat is just an encyclopaedia lookup.

Do mobiles use TCP/IP? Okay, but then what is the problem at hand?

Comment: Maybe the FAQ should be changed then.  I wonder how 21st century mobile phones are not computers? What about tablet computers?  Are these computers?  What about the Galaxy Note?  Tablet or mobile phone? And with the encyclopaedia lookup you could as well end up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(telecommunications))

Comment: Btw. I routinely connect a mouse, display and keyboard to my mobile phone, connect to wireless networks and with emacs installed develop software on it.  In fact, I bought it in order to replace my notebook.

Comment: @artistoex: `Computers, but not smart phones` is pretty clear to me, the question was off-topic according to the current FAQ. If you want the FAQ to be changed to "_smart phones may or may not be computers depending on what hardware you may or may not add while you are using them_", then why not suggest it?